# How to remove certain Strings from a sharedPreferences at the user's input in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Im using android studio to create a music app and I am quite a novice programmer. I have created a sharedPreferences to store the songs for the user's "Favourite playlist" , and storing the data works, however when I try to use 'notifyDataSetChanged' to tell the observer that the user wants to remove a song, it doesn't change the sharedPreferences. Thus, when reopening the app, the songs are not removed from the playlist and still show up in the xml folder.

This is the function that adds the songs to the sharedpreferences :

```
public void addToFavourite(View view) {
    String songId = view.getContentDescription().toString();
    Song song = SongCollection.songSearchById(songId);
    favourite.add(song);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(favourite);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("list", json);
    editor.apply();
    Toast.makeText(this,"Song added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

This is the function that should remove the songs on the click of the remove button :

```
holder.removebtn.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            HomePage.favourite.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You just need to confirm that does  `HomePage.favourite.remove(position);` line removes the item from shared prefs? just rectify it once.

Comment: It removes from my Arraylist which I am using for the playlist but does not remove from shared pref

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I was not actually changing the shared preferences file and all I needed to do was to create another Editor.